# How to change the color of text in text field by selecting color from a drop down menu in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to select a value from

```js
<div class = "form-group" >
  <label for = "" class = "" > Select Colour < /label> 
  <div class = "dropdown" >
 <button class = "btn _select_color dropdown-toggle"
type = "button"
id = "dropdownMenu1"
data - toggle = "dropdown"
aria - haspopup = "true"
aria - expanded = "false" > Green < span class = "caret _right" > < /span> <span _text_display="Green" class="color green"></span > < /button> 
  <ul class = "dropdown-menu _select_color_drop"
aria - labelledby = "dropdownMenu1" >

  <li > < span _text_display = "Green"
class = "color green" > < /span></li >
  
  <li > < span _text_display = "Red"
class = "color red" > < /span></li >
  
  <li > < span _text_display = "Yellow"
class = "color yellow" > < /span></li >
  
  <li > < span _text_display = "Brown"
class = "color brown" > < /span></li >
  
  <li > < span _text_display = "Orange"
class = "color orange" > < /span></li >
  
  <li > < span _text_display = "Pink"
class = "color pink" > < /span></li >
  
  <li > < span _text_display = "Silver"
class = "color silver" > < /span></li >
  
  <li > < span _text_display = "Bule"
class = "color blue"
name = "blue"
value = "blue" > < /span></li >
  
  <li > < span _text_display = "TEAL"
class = "color TEAL" > < /span></li >
  
  <li > < span _text_display = "NAVY"
class = "color NAVY" > < /span></li >
  
  <li > < span _text_display = "PURPLE"
class = "color PURPLE" > < /span></li >
  
  <li > < span _text_display = "OLIVE"
class = "color OLIVE" > < /span></li >
  
  <li > < span _text_display = "LIME"
class = "color LIME" > < /span></li >
  
  <input type = "hidden"
name = "_color"
value = "Green" > < /ul> 
 </div> 
  </div>
```

and i want the color will be selected in

```html
<form name="myForm" action="#">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="message"> Text Here</label>
    <textarea name="txt1" id="message" cols="30" rows="9" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <input type="text" value="something" onclick="this.value='';this.style.color=_color;" /> </div>
</form>
```

The color selected from the color list must be reflect in the textfile. I am new to HTML CSS and JS.

Comment: Reformat the first code snippet you posted. It's very hard to read

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic implementation of how I understood your question.

```js
var colorSelect = document.getElementById("selectColor")
var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
function applyColor(){
  var color = colorSelect.value;
  textbox.style.color = color
}

applyColor();


colorSelect.addEventListener("change", applyColor);
```

```html
<textarea id="textbox">
text
</textarea>

<select id="selectColor">
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
  <option value="red"> red </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your code, but usually to change colors and accomplish changes to the UI, it's easiest to manipulate classes with the specific change. Here's some code and a link to codepen illustrating this:

## HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>

<select id="menu">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="black">Black</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

## CSS (Stylus)

```
#box
   width 100px
   height 100px

.red
  background red

.blue
  background blue

.black
  background black

.green
  background green
```

## JS

```
(function() {

  var box           = document.getElementById("box");
  var menu          = document.getElementById("menu");
  var currentValue  = menu.value            // grabs current menu selection

  box.classList.add(currentValue);          // adds class to element wanting to change color

  // event listener and function to handle change
  menu.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    var color = menu.value;                 
    box.classList.remove(currentValue);     // removes current color class 
    box.classList.add(color);               // adds new color
    currentValue = color;                   // resets current color variable for next change
  })

})()
```

https://codepen.io/codyj/pen/Pjyzmz?editors=1111